# Relay to connect a DC motor to Arduino using external DC power supply

Tags: arduino, relay

Trying to control a 12 V DC pump using an Arduino. Got a relay that has just the labels 10A 250 VAC, 15A 250 V AC, 10A 250 V AC. So does this mean that this relay would not accept a DC source as an external powersupply?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine. From the [datasheet](https://www.generationrobots.com/media/JQC-3FF-v1.pdf) it's rated at 10 A and 30 V\$_\mathrm{DC}\$.